# Am I measuring the performance of my Multiple Linear Regression model correct?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

This might be a little bit of a silly question (and probably trivial question) but I am new to machine learning. This can probably be easily deduced from the code I came up with, and it's not an excuse for a poorly formulated question. If you find this question poorly formulated, please inform me so I can update it.

I trained a multiple linear regression model and I want to see how well it performs a given data set. So, I googled around and I found [a nice article](http://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning-evaluate-linear-regression-model/#15.-Model-Evaluation-Metrics-for-Regression) explaining me how to find out the "error" of the predicted values, from the true ones. A couple of options it gave me were: [image]

I applied all of them and they gave me incredibly high values, so I don't know whether these are correct or how I should interpret them.

**Output the article was receiving:**

- 10.0
- 150.0
- 12.2474487139

**Output that my model received:**

- 7514.293659640891
- 83502864.03257468
- 9137.990152794797

As a quick reference, these are my true / predicted values
[image]

**The 'TLDR' question:** Am I measuring my error correctly using the above mentioned methods, and are these results implying that my model performs incredibly bad? (This didn't seem like it, when I compared the prediction with the true values)

[Here](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/b62ab1baad4e7ace6404cd73ea19191e/50_Startups.csv) you can have a look at the data set I am using.

The code I used to create the model and predict values ( I tried to remove the unneeded code )

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import metrics

dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values # Independent variables
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values # Dependent variable

# Encode categorical data into numerical values (1, 2, 3)
# For example; New york becomes 1 and Florida becomes 2
labelencoder_states = LabelEncoder()
# We just want to apply this to the state column, since this has categorical data
states_encoded = labelencoder_states.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
# Update the states with the new encoded data
X[:, 3] = states_encoded

# Now that we have the categories as numerical data, 
# we can split them into multiple dummy variables:
# Split the categories into columns (more optimal)
# Tell it too look at the state column
onehotencoder_states = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
# Actually transforms them into columns
X = onehotencoder_states.fit_transform(X).toarray()

# Avoiding the Dummy Variable Trap
# Remove the first column from X
# Since; dummy variables -1
X = X[:, 1:]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
# In this case we are going to use 40 of the 50 records for training
# and ten of the 50 for testing, hence the 0.2 split ratio
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Create a regressor
regressor = LinearRegression()
# Fit the model to the training data
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions on the test set, using our model
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

# Evaluating the model (Am I doing this correct?)

# How well did it do?
print(metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
print(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print(np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)))
```

Comment: Your labels are one hot encoded and you are doing regression? I think what you want to do is classification.

Comment: I did that to split up the states into their own columns. Like I said, I am new to machine learning and I am following a machine learning course. Sadly they didn't include a method to measure the performance of the model.

Comment: @UmangGupta I added a screenshot of the true/predicted data to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: @UmangGupta The average value of your data looks large, which means that the average value of the error might be fine. Can you print out the result of sqrt mean square error divided by the average absolute value of the target variable in the test set? You can't say that sqrt of mean squared error "is large" without some notion of how large the error is relative to the size of your observations themselves.

Comment: By way of example, imagine one data set where you are predicting the prices of stocks, and accuracy in the range of pennies will be important. Now imagine another problem where you are predicting the distances between far away galaxies. An accuracy in the range of billions of miles might be very good.

Comment: @ely If this is what you mean with the "dividing it by the average absolute value of the target variable in the test set": `metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred) / np.mean(y_test)` then the output is roughly 683

Comment: @ely By the way, your example really gave me a better insight. The fact that the error will be somewhat proportional to the data set I am using. Thank you.

Comment: @GerritLuimstra You need `np.mean(np.abs(y_test))`, so that negative numbers don't have a cancellative effect on the mean (we are interested in the average 'size' of `y_test`). Second, you need `sqrt` of the numerator there, because the *squared* error will be much larger. If you think of it like units in physics, squared error is like area, a squared unit. But to compare fairly with `np.mean(np.abs(y_test))` you need the regular unit, not squared.

Comment: @ely Ah, I get it. I didn't understand the absolute part, but since I don't have  negative values, it makes sense. The answer is still roughly 683.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is [MAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) since your numbers are so big.

Comment: @J63 I will have a look into that, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's answer it:
I think you are measuring (at least with code) correctly. But:

1. Who is telling you that the relationship is linear? You are trying to predict profit (right?). I would say that a linear regression will probably not work very well. So I am not surprised that you don't get a good result.
2. To get an idea on how your prediction works, try to plot predicted vs real and check how good your points stay on a line.

To summarize: the fact that you get big values does not mean that your code is wrong. Most probably the relationship is not linear.

On a side note: using categorical variables may be a source of problems. Have you tried to do your linear regression without state? What are your results? Which variable are the most important in your regression? You should check that. What is your R squared?

I hope this helps, Umberto

Comment: I guess you are right. Thank you for the answer. You almost got the objective right; "Try to predict the profit of a startup company based on the amount of money they spend on r&d, administration, marketing and the state they are located in, to figure out in what companies to invest."

Comment: If you want to try some linear regression, try the Boston house price dataset: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_boston.html that is something that you can try your models on. The relationship is not linear but you get quite a reasonable prediction if you try... I suggest you try. With startups is hardly possible to infer the profit from data like how much you invest in research, administration and so on...